# How do you determine an interpretation and a model for $\left((x \wedge y) \rightarrow (x \vee y)\right)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> How do you determine an interpretation and a model for $\left((x
> \wedge y) \rightarrow (x \vee y)\right)$?

I've read several articles on the internet about "interpretation" and "model" but I still don't understand it (explanation is too complicated for me).

But I think when you make a truth table using that given formula, each line of that table represents an interpretation. Here is the truth table for the formula:

```
 x  |  y  |  x∧y  |  x∨y  | (x∧y) -> (x∨y)
-------------------------------------------
 1  |  1  |   1   |   1   |       1
 1  |  0  |   0   |   1   |       1
 0  |  1  |   0   |   1   |       1
 0  |  0  |   0   |   0   |       1
```

Let's say I want write the interpretation for the third line. How would this look like? Like that? $I = \left\{x=0, y = 1\right\}$ ?

And about "model" I don't have any ideas :o

Comment: "Interpretation" and "model" can be synonyms along with "semantics" and possibly "structure" and "valuation" too. They may also be used together in non-synonymous but closely related ways, e.g. an interpretation is part of a structure, a valuation is the underlying function of an interpretation. Occasionally different communities have conflicting definitions. As an important consideration, the notion of "model"/"interpretation" varies with the logic (among a few other things). So you can't naively translate your understanding of what a term means from one article to another.

Comment: For propositional logic, an *interpretation* is a mapping of the propositional letters into $\{ \text {TRUE }, \text {FALSE} \}$ (or $\{ 1,0 \}$) also called *valuation*.

Comment: An interpretation that satisfies the formula (i.e. that assigns to the formula the value TRUE) is a *model*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then the interpretation for line $3$ of the truth table  can be written like that, right? $$I(x) = 0, I(y) = 1$$ or rather $$I = \left\{0,1\right\} ?$$

Comment: Yes; the first way is more clear.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you! :) And to determine the model, I will just pick ALL interpretations that are true?

Comment: Every int that is true is a model.